# I accidentally deleted asset resource folder in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I accidentally deleted asset resource folder in Xcode 8 by removing it to the thrash. After recover it from thrash i can see the asset folder in finder but i cannot see it in the project structure in Xcode 8. Someone please help.

Comment: It is in your projects directory you have to drag it into your project

Comment: It worked. Thank you for ur help.

Answer (score 1):

That is available in your project directory.

1. You can add it bundle by dragging it.
2. You can add it by left clicking in project navigator in Xcode. Then select **Add files to xxx**